# How can I enable a user to save a .jpg file into my resource folder

Tags: vb.net

How can I enable a user to save a .jpg file into my resource folder.  I can save it in the resource folder by using the relative path "....\Resources" but my Resource manager does not recognise it. Do I need to turn it into an Image object first? If so how.  Many thanks for your help

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: the Resources folder is just where the images etc live while you write the app.  when you compile they become part of the exe. So, you cant do that.  That is what those `Users\NAME\...` folders are for.  Depending where your app is installed you may not have permission to save to a sub folder anyway

Comment: Sorry, Code is belowDim NewCopyOfPic As String = "..\..\Resources\" & Me.txt_Name.Text & "_" & Me.lbl_Data_IDNumber.Text & ".jpg"
        Dim PicToSaveCurrentFilePath As String = OpenFD.FileName

        If System.IO.File.Exists(PicToSaveCurrentFilePath) = True Then

            System.IO.File.Copy(PicToSaveCurrentFilePath, NewCopyOfPic)
        End If

Comment: sorry, that has not helped has it. As you may have guessed, I have not used this site before

Comment: @Alastair You should edit your question and add in your code, making sure to format it as code (use the `{ }` icon in the toolbar). Also, if you want to include code in comments, use a ` (backtick) to surround it. e.g. ``I have a variable called `myVar`.``

Comment: copying a file to the Resources folder does not and will not make it available via `My.Resources`.  See my first comment